# $D:\operatorname{Aut}(G)\to\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak g)$ is an injective group homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

**Let $G$ be a connected Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$. Aut(G) is the group of automorphisms of G. It is known that the automorphism group Aut($\mathfrak g$) is a Lie group and a closed subgroup of GL$(\mathfrak g)$
The tangent map (at $e$) of any automorphism of $G$ is an automorphism of $\mathfrak g$.
I want to show that the induced map**

**$\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{\operatorname{Aut}} D : \Aut(G) \to \Aut(\mathfrak  g)$**

**is an injective group homomorphism.**

I have to check two things: that $D$ is a group homomorphism and that it is injective.

Proving that it is a group homomorphism:

$D : \Aut(G) \to \Aut(\mathfrak  g): f \mapsto T_ef$

I have that for $f,g \in \Aut(G)$,

$D(f \circ g)=T_e(f \circ g)=T_{g(e)}f\circ T_eg=T_ef\circ T_eg=D(f)\circ D(g)$

Now for the injectivity part

I have to check that the kernel is trivial

Following the corrections in the comments I think the kernel is defined like this :

$  \operatorname{Ker}(D)=\{f\in \Aut(G): Df=id_{T_eG}\}=\{f\in \Aut(G): T_ef=id_{T_eG}\}$

where $id_{T_eG}$ is the identity over $T_eG$ which is the identiy element of the group $Aut(\mathfrak g)$

**I am stuck at this point. How do I conclude from here that $f=id_G$?**

I know $T_e id_G=id_{T_eG}$ . So I have that $Df=T_ef=id_{T_eG}=T_e id_G$ from which I  am not sure how to justify that $T_ef=T_e id_G$ implies $f=id_G$. Besides don't I need to use the connectedness of the Lie group?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez so I rewrote the kernel in the edit, looks good? What should I do next?

Comment: Is f a Lie group homom?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez OK I fixed that. See the end of the post again . I  am not sure how to justify that $T_ef=T_e id_G$ implies $f=id_G$. Besides don't I need to use the connectedness of the Lie group?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez So you suggest that I don't analize the kernel but  extract it from the proof of Lie's second theorem?  However I was reading the proof here http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/13F-Lie/Notes/Lec%2012.pdf  and I don't see it there. I also was looking up in differntial geometry books but I can't find anything that helps me with injectivity and the hints down here are really not helping.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Note that essentially by definition, for any $x\in\mathfrak g$ and $f\in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$, we have $\exp(Dfx)=f\exp(x)$.

Then use the fact that $G$ is connected to conclude that if $Df=\operatorname{id}_{\mathfrak g}$, then $f$ is the identity.

**Hint 2**: Suppose $Df$ is the identity and consider the set $\{g\in G\mid f(g)=g\}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how do you use that G is connected? In the comments it si suggested that I have to use Lie's second theorem which is: If g and h are isomorphic Lie algebras, then G and H are locally isomorphic Lie groups. But I don't see how that helps here or how connectedness is required by these theorem

Comment: No, you don't even need the fact that it's a Lie group for the last part. It's a purely topological observation that the set of fixed points is a subgroup and that an open subgroup contains the connected component.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? I am alredy 2 days trying to do this. I don't know how to use this hints to conclude injectivity. The first hint doesn't seem to be realted with proving injectivity and in the second why would $Df=\operatorname{id}_{\mathfrak g}$, imply $f$ is the identity. I only know that the opposite is true, which is a theorem in Lie'smooth manifolds book but I can't find that the opposite is true for the component of the identity